# Why does this line not output my text file?

Tags: c++

I am currently reading a book that is teaching me about C++ and I have run into a problem.  I looked around the Internet a bit to see if I can find an answer but I don't seem to understand them to well.  I wrote this code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    // Writing the poem
    string poem = "\n\tI never saw a man who looked";
    poem.append("\n\tWith such a wistful eye");
    poem.append("\n\tUpon that little tent of blue");
    poem.append("\n\tWhich prisoners call the sky");
    
    // More stuff
    ofstream writer("poem.txt");
    
    if(!writer) {
        cout << "Error opening file for output" << endl;
        return -1;  // Signal a termination
    }
        writer << poem << endl;
        writer.close();
    
    // Teminates the program
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem specifically is this line `writer << poem << endl;`.  But I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong.  I am fairly certain I did the exercise correct.

Let me restate my issue.  I have a text file that is generated with a poem.  What I am trying to do is output the lines of text in the file to the console (terminal).  The book that I am reading to do `writer << poem << endl;`.  I did that but nothing is output, it just generates the file with the text and thats it.

---

### A few long moments later.

As it turns out I was just being dumb and I later realized that the problem was more of me not reading/understanding the text to it's fullest.  I was under the impression that this code was meant to output the text.  I was wrong, but the following answer really helped me!  Thanks.

Comment: Code looks fine. The file gets created but it's just empty?

Comment: The code works fine so what's the problem? Add the problem instead of this long story

Comment: @AndyG I checked the file both with GEdit and Vim(Just in case?).  The poem is in there.  The file generation seems to work.

Comment: @joeldesante: I don't understand. What's the problem, then?

Comment: Are you thinking that the contents of the text file should be printed to the terminal?

Comment: `The problem is that when I run this file in the terminal it compiles and everything but when it is run the text files contents wont output.`? unclear what you say.

Comment: *"... the text files contents wont output."* - Are you expecting the output to be driven to the text file *and* echoed to the terminal? That doesn't happen magically. If that's what you want to happen, then that's what *you* have to code to make happen.

Comment: @AndyG The contents of the file wont output into the terminal... It just seems to write a file and thats it.

Comment: @joeldesante: Can you explain why you think that should happen? There is something missing from your mental model in how streams work in C++ and I'd like to try to fix that :-)

Comment: @joeldesante *" It just seems to write a file and thats it."* : that's because that is *exactly* what this code is written to do: write to a file; *nothing else*. If you want both file and terminal output, *you* have to do both. Put `std::cout << poem << '\n';` in your code, pretty-much anywhere after you setup the `poem` variable.

Comment: Yes that is the role of `class ofstream` to read the content back to the terminal then use `ifstream`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh ok, then just so that I understand what does `writer << poem << endl;` do?

Comment: @joeldesante: `cout` will write to the terminal, `writer` will write to the file. They are separate streams.

Comment: @joeldesante That line invokes the overloaded `operator <<` taking a `std::ostream` reference on the left side, and a `std::string` const-reference on the right side. That operator eventually writes the string to the target stream, in this case, the file stream you opened. And fyi, it behaves *identically* when writing to *any* `std::ostream` reference, including `std::cout`, the wrapper for `stdout`.

Comment: It does "output the text"... _to a file_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `ofstream` writes to files not to the screen so to get the content of the file to your program then use `class ifstream`.

In your program if you want the text to be written to a file then read back to your program:

- add this code right after closing the file after writting `writer.close()`:

  ```
  ifstream inFile("poem.txt");
  string sLine;

  while(getline(inFile, sLine))
      cout << sLine << endl;
  inFile.close();
  ```
- Or simply use an object of class `fstream` doing the two tasks once: writting/reading.